# Why Lockscreen in my Lumia 525 lags while unlocking?

Tags: lock-screen, nokia-lumia-525

I unlock my phone the display shows **Resuming..** like [image: this]

after 5 sec its showing LockScreen why its happening. I have used *Tetra Lock Screen* for a month and i uninstalled it last week. before using Tetra app i had *Live Lockscreen Beta*.

Comment: What app is it unlocking to?

Comment: There's no app running. Start screen itself showing like this before swiping up (i.e., before Unlocking phone). While pushing power button the phone starts with the screen i showed above, after this only lock screen itself shown

Comment: It's because you used Live Lock Screen. It does that to the phone (read the reviews). Restarting your phone should fix it.

Comment: I restarted so many times but the same thing again..

Comment: Did you also deinstall the live lockscreen app?

Comment: Yes, i uninstalled both @Thomas

Comment: I really hate "reset your phone" answers, but it would appear that that's what you'd have to do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got an answer that I went to **lockscreen** option under Settings, there I changed all possible things i.e., I chose bing as background abd disabled password also quick status apps are removed, where earlier I had whatsapp, email, messaging & call history after removing those apps, made a try to unlock the device by locking the issue explained above in the post disappeared. Yes, it happened.

Thanks to all.